# CDI Bean Scoping during Injection is not working

Tags: jsf, cdi

I want to give on-the-go scope to a pojo bean in CDI during injection.

I created a plain bean and injected the same as `@javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped` in a `@javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped` Managed Bean like this:

```
@Inject
@ApplicationScoped
Pojo pojo;
```

// POJO Class

```
Class Pojo {
  private String var;

  public Pojo() {

  }

  public String getVar() {
    return var;
  }

  public void setVar(String var) {
    this.var = var;
  }
}
```

The Pojo bean's populated values could not be restored in a new view bean when I inject using the same syntax.

But it works when I use `@ApplicationScoped` in the class declaration instead, followed by non-scoped injection, like this:

```
@ApplicationScoped
Class Pojo {
      private String var;
```

Injection:

```
@Inject
Pojo pojo;
```

The former case gets resolved when I make a producer and qualifier but I feel this would be an overhead I should do without. Being new to CDI, I want to ask what I am really missing here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scope and Context management are a very powerful feature in CDI. It is also part of the business logic of the components (an `@ApplicationScoped` bean won't be developed the same way than a `@RequestScoped`), that's why the scope is link to bean definition.
An injection point is only a place where you consume a bean and not a place where you define it, so there is no way to define the scope of a bean at the injection point at spec level.
Now if you really want to use this feature you could develop a portable extension to add this possibility. But you'll probably have to work on a qualifier system as well since scope is not used in bean resolving process (i.e. 2 beans with the same type in different scope will be in conflict for a given injection point if they don't have specific qualifier).

Comment: Understandable. I was always wondering why one couldn't have a neutral injectable bean in CDI which could have any scope during injection. I think to achieve this for a different scope I would also need to modify my current extension (qualifier & producer), or a new extension, for a different scope.